# Can basic column liquid chromatography separate two extremely similar alkaloids?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Say a sample has two alkaloids, one with a molecular weight of 521.44 g/mol and one with a weight of 521.66 g/mol.

Would column chromatography be able to separate these two alkaloids?

Also, what if a sample has, say 15 different alkaloids. Will all of these separate in liquid column chromatography?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar molar mass does not say much about the alkaloid similarity, nor the alkaloid count. More information is needed, including chromatographic properties of alkaloids and the parameters of chromatography system.

Comment: TLC may give you a clue but the reality is it is very difficult to predict the exact behaviour of compounds on chromatography columns. I would think you would have a far better chance with prep HPLC.

Comment: Test it on a small scale (eg TLC) and see. It is extremely hard to predict the outcome but testing is cheap. It might be worth testing a variety of elutants or column materials. There is no easy shortcut.

Comment: Thank Matt. If they didn't separate via TLC what would be the next step? I mean, what do manufacturers use to separate alkaloids that wouldn't separate via tlc?

Comment: MS-guided prep HPLC is the current goto method

Comment: Could you recommend a company that could perform this for me?